# Rails - column not found for defined 'has_many' relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I define a `Post` class which can link or be linked to multiple posts. To do this I added a `PostLink` class which specifies `post_to` and `post_from`.

I generated the `PostLink` class by `rails g model post_link from_post:integer to_post:integer` and of course `rake db:migrate`, and added

```
belongs_to :from_post, :class_name => 'Post' 
belongs_to :to_post, :class_name => 'Post'
```

to the class.

And I also have `has_many :post_links` in my `Post` class.

I ran `rails console` and `Post.new.post_links` and got `nil` printed out, which is expected. However after I save a `Post` using

```
p = Post.new
p.save
```

and then run `p.post_links`, it prints out the following error message:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: post_links.post_id: SELECT "post_links".* 
FROM "post_links"  WHERE "post_links"."post_id" = 1
```

So anybody know why after saving it to the database `post_link` can not be accessed?

Comment: Can you provide us your schema.rb?

Comment: Did you define the `post_id` column in `post_link`? And, are you able to provide the schema.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `has_many :post_links` association in `Post` throws an error because it assumes the foreign key in post_links is `post_id` by default. Since you are using `from_post_id` and `to_post_id`, you will have to find a way to group the post_links for "from" posts and "to" posts to get the total set of post_links for a post.

One approach could be to define two associations on `Post` and an additional method to add the sets together:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :from_post_links, :class_name => 'PostLink', :foreign_key => :from_post_id
  has_many :to_post_links, :class_name => 'PostLink', :foreign_key => :to_post_id'

  def post_links
    from_post_links + to_post_links
  end

end
```

As another option, you could provide special sql to the association to group the sets in a single query:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :post_links, :finder_sql => Proc.new {
    %Q{
      SELECT *
      FROM post_links pl
      WHERE pl.to_post_id = #{id} 
      OR pl.from_post_id = #{id}
    }
  }
```